# Javascript pop up window css and click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a pop up window which contains form to fill out the details. My need is, I need to show the form inside the pop up window with the css styles applied to it.

Currently I have loaded the form inside the pop up window but it is not taking the style applied to it. How do I get the styles to be applied on it. (I don't want to load the .html page in windows pop up)

When I click on the submit link in the pop up, it should clone the `.clone` div on the page and pop up should get closed.

here is my current js

```
function myFunction() {
    var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=500, height=400");
    myWindow.document.write($(".content").html());
    myWindow.document.close();
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/erv3ebj1/4/)**

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: use css in <style> tags is one way

Comment: Don't use `window.open`, use a [jquery-ui dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or bootstrap modal.

Comment: window.open is opening a new tab, and your css is not getting applied to that page

Comment: @freedomn-m for some reason I am forced to use window pop up only. So is this struggle.

Comment: Frequently, people ask questions like this because they are unaware of newer options that provide improved user-experience (UX) and are vastly easier/quicker to code against / work with.    In this case you have an external requirement.

Answer (score 0):

put ur `css` inside the `div` '`content`'

check this link
http://jsfiddle.net/erv3ebj1/5/

Comment: It did work.. But is it the valid way to use it? and any idea about submit button function?

Comment: you are using <a> inside form ,use input type=submit with form action and method type

Comment: That did the job but how about div cloning on the page when I submit the form?

Comment: simple, use ajax to reload the load div after submitting the form

Answer (score 0):

Adding some like this may work

```
myWindow.append($("<link/>", 
    { rel: "stylesheet", href: "file://path/to/style.css", type: "text/css" }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try opening it in an iframe that's hidden until you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Put CSS under `content div` and use internal css `<style>`.

I would advice to use it before `form` tag

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/erv3ebj1/10/)

Answer (score -1):

Please try this one:

```
function myFunction() {
    var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=500, height=400");

    myWindow.document.write($(".content").html());

    myWindow.document.close();

    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/erv3ebj1/8/)

Comment: You should add details to the answer showing how this fixes the problem - the jsfiddle is not enough.   As it stands, the code you've added is identical to the code in the question, so it looks like a good candidate for a *down vote*.   In the fiddle you've added extra info - just needs to be explained here